# To click a button on a UserForm in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have searched on the Internet for a few days but I still cannot find the way out. I would be really appreciated if I could get some hints from you guys here. Here is the details of what I am going to do:

I got a read-only Workbook called A, with a button 1 on it. By clicking button 1, a User-form containing a list-box and a button 2 with macro will pop out. The result will be printed on sheet 2 on workbook A.

What I want to do is that, using another workbook B, to call a VBA script to open workbook A and click button 1 for activate the User-form. Then,then select all the rows and run macro by clicking button 2. Finally, copy the value on sheet 2 to the workbook B.

To simplify the problem, I write some code to illustrate the case.

On Workbook A:
Button 1:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Button 2:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim y As Long, z As Long
    z = 1
    With Me.ListBox1
        For y = 0 To .ListCount
            On Error GoTo EH
            If .Selected(y) = True Then
                For i = 1 To ListBox1.ColumnCount
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(z, i) = .List(y, i - 1)
                Next i
                z = z + 1
            End If
        Next y
    End With
    Unload Me

    End
EH:
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

UserForm:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

ListBox1.Clear


With ListBox1
    ListBox1.ColumnCount = 3
    ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "60;60;60"
    .AddItem
    .List(0, 0) = 1
    .List(0, 1) = 2
    .List(0, 2) = 3
    .AddItem
    .List(1, 0) = 4
    .List(1, 1) = 5
    .List(1, 2) = 6
End With


End Sub
```

On Workbook B, I do the following:

```
Sub selectsheet()
    Application.Run Workbooks("WorksbookA").Worksheets("sheet1").Shapes("Button1").OnAction
    ListBox1.Selected(1) = True
    UserForm1.Button2_click
    Worksheets("sheet2").range("A1:B3").copy
    Workbooks("WorksbookB").Worksheets("sheet1").range("A1").select
    selection.paste
End Sub
```

The vba seems fine because I could run it. But it sticks at the Application.Run. I am sorry that I am not a good at programming and also explaining this messy stuff. But I would be really appreciated if any of you could give a hand to me. Thanks.

Comment: What happens on the Application.Run line? Do you get an error message? What does it say?

Comment: It successfully opens workbook A and the UserForm but then nothing proceeds. Maybe it is a bit confusing for my question, actually what I want to do is to fill in the userform in workbook A automatically using vba in workbook B ( because workbook A is a read only file). Sorry for my poor ability on explaining.

Comment: .onAction should be set to something. E.g., Worksheets(1).Shapes(1).OnAction = "ShapeClick" ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834436.aspx)  Also, you should remove the "Application.Run" completely as it is unnecessary.